# vm.max_map_count is too low

Tags: elasticsearch

I am moving from elasticsearch 2.x to 5.x and facing this problem while starting up.

```
[2017-02-28T14:38:24,490][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-02-28T14:38:24,494][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [node1] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [8192] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
max size virtual memory [52729364480] for user [elastic] is too low, increase to [unlimited]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

My yml looks as follows

```
node.name:  node1
network.host: _global_
```

I have downloaded the elasticsearch tarball and OS is SLES11Sp4

Elasticsearch bootstrap checks are defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/bootstrap-checks.html). But after playing around with /etc/security/limits.conf and  /etc/sysctl.conf, still i cant bring it up.

In rpm installation, these things are supposedly taken care automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This is the setting which finally worked.

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
* hard memlock unlimited
* soft memlock unlimited
* hard nofile 65536
* soft nofile 65536
*  - as unlimited
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.max_map_count = 262144
vm.swappiness = 1
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: atul-es-kerberos
node.name:  node1
network.host: _eth0:ipv4_
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["atul.labs.com"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

#### 1. Linux

The `vm.max_map_count=262144` setting should be set permanently in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

> grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> vm.max_map_count=262144

**OR**

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: Official instruction is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Answer (score 1):

For Docker on Windows, you should:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: there's no docker-machine on the most recent versions of docker for windows. Instead, you need to use `wsl -d docker-desktop` in order to invoke sysctl

Answer (score 1):

If you are running docker using [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) on macOS you need to ssh into the VM to set the `max_map_count` parameter as follows

```
colima ssh
```

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```